# How to print the table using foreign key information?

Tags: php, mysql, select, foreign-key-relationship

Friends i have 3 table as follows

```
create table departments
(
  department_id int(20) AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  department_name varchar(30) not null
);

create table designations
(
  designation_id int(20) AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  designation_name varchar(30) not null
);
create table employees
(
 employee_id int(20) AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
 employee_name varchar(30) not null,
 department int,
 designation int,
 salary int(20) not null,
 FOREIGN KEY (department) REFERENCES departments(department_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (designation) REFERENCES designations(designation_id),
);
```

These are my 3 tables. Now i need to view the employee table as below

employee_id | employee_name | designation_name | department_name |employee_salary

How do i get it??  Below is my error program

```
<?php
$database_connection = new mysqli("localhost","root","","employee_application");
if($database_connection->connect_error)
     die ("connection failed".$database_connection->connect_error);

$sql_query = "select employees.employee_name,employees.designation,employees.department,employees.employee_salary,departments.department_id,designations.designation_id
              from employees,departments,designations
              where employees.department = departments.department_id and employees.designation = designations.designation_id";

$result=$database_connection->query($sql_query);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    echo "<table>";
    while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$rows["id"]."<td>";
        echo "<td>".$rows["name"]."<td>";
        echo "<td>".$rows["department"]."<td>";
        echo "<td>".$rows["designation"]."<td>";
        echo "<td>".$rows["salary"]."<td>";
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
else{
echo "Table is empty";
}
?>
```

Comment: what error you are getting.?

Comment: limit exceeds and while loop statements are wrong i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask for employee_salary but in your table, the row is called 'salary'. Pay attention to that !

Moreover, you should use LEFT OUTER JOIN for your SQL query like this :

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.employee_name, e.salary, des.designation_name, dep.department_name
FROM employees e
LEFT OUTER JOIN designations des ON e.designation = des.designation_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN departments dep ON e.department = dep.department_id
```

You have to change these lines as well :

```
echo "<td>".$rows["employee_id"]."<td>";
echo "<td>".$rows["employee_name"]."<td>";
echo "<td>".$rows["department_name"]."<td>";
echo "<td>".$rows["designation_name"]."<td>";
echo "<td>".$rows["salary"]."<td>";
```

Comment: i just want to print employee id, employee name, employee salary, designation name and designation salary. I don't want designation and department id to be printed so how do i do tht

Comment: And statements inside while loop is not executing. Y?

Comment: No problemo. Don't forget to always use the same names in your php variables as in your MySQL tables, unless you use aliases.

Answer (score 1):

TRY WITH THIS

```
select employees.employee_id,
employees.employee_name,
designations.designation_name,
departments.department_name,
employees.salary as employee_salary
  from employees
  left join departments on employees.department = departments.department_id 
  left join designations on employees.designation = designations.designation_id
```

Comment: what is the purpose of as in the 5th line of the code

Comment: Its working in mysql server but how to get the information through while loop